# Accessing a TextBox through Viewmodel and Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, class, mvvm, textbox

I have created a C# WPF program, in which I have a `TextBox`. I want this `TextBox` to give feedback of events using a `viewmodel`.

Simplified example: When a button is clicked, the `TextBox` Displays `"...Button clicked"`.

I currently have it in the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //.....
    public void FeedbackPanel(string text)
    {
        if (FeedbkPanelTextBox != null)
        {
            if (text != null)
            {
                FeedbkPanelTextBox.AppendText(text + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                FeedbkPanelTextBox.AppendText("Null\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I move this code behind to a `viewmodel` and use binding in the `view`?

*Edited*

Comment: You should at least list a _few_ of the things you've tried, so we will understand your level of knowledge. Because the simple answer is: "they're classes. You can do all sorts of class things with them". But if you were to give us a list of what you tried, it will probably become obvious what part of OO programming you don't understand.

Comment: I hope you feel better. But here's a suggestion to self-learn. Go learn basic Object-Oriented Programming concepts before trying to program WPF.  Almost all WPF examples or tutorials will assume that you know the basics of OOP, and they will not teach you those basics. In the meantime, WPF assumes that you already know the basics. This is actually a very simple question, in WPF, or WinForms, or ASP.NET. Same answer always.

Comment: There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: We'd rather help you than answer the question

Comment: The fact that you asked the question proves that you didn't understand some of the basics. What do you even mean "in it's own class"? Are you talking about user controls, but maybe didn't know the term?

Comment: Also, please try to be more specific. Are you saying that you want a separate class that has a textbox in it, and you want to use that class in the main form, but you then don't know how the main form would access the textbox in the separate class?

Comment: _"I can't find a simple way of having this FeedbackPanel() work in its own class"_ -- as-is, that problem statement is way too broad. Why do you want that method in a separate class in the first place? Do you have any specific goals or constraints for how that class should relate to your `MainWindow` class? What have you tried so far, in terms of putting it in its own class? Why and how did what you try so far not work? What did it do, and how was that different from what you wanted it to do. Please help us help you; your question just isn't answerable in a practical way at the moment.

Comment: _"your question just isn't answerable in a practical way"_ -- and to be clear, there are lots of ways to answer your question that would work given the broadly stated goal. But there are _so many_ ways, it's impossible to know which one is actually the way you want or need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast example:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonClickedFeedbackICommand.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonClickedFeedbackICommand"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox x:Name="tbFeedback"
                 Text="{Binding ClickedFeedback}"
                 MinWidth="50" 
                 Background="SlateGray"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Content="Click" 
                Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tbFeedback, Path=Text}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is your View. In order to support what you said we need a way to communicate with that other class. Our button will use a command and a CommandParameter which will leverage the access to the Text property of the TextBox.

Here is your simple ViewModel :

```
public class ViewModel
{

    public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        TestCommand = new TestCommand(this);
    }

    public void FeedbackPanel(string text)
    {
        if (text != null)
        {
            if (text != null)
            {
                text += (text + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                text += ("Null\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the Command:

```
public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    public ViewModel _vm { get; set; }

    public TestCommand(ViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _vm.FeedbackPanel(parameter.ToString());
    }
}
```

You may choose to send another thing in that CommandParameter. In think the flow respects your needs. Feel free to play with it for a while.

Comment: @noodles If you use code behind, indeed you will be able to handle the Button's Click event easily but after that you will need a way to call FeedbackPanel(string text) which resides in another class. And that's not all, you still need a way to get back to your TextBox. Either you define method in MainWindow which will receive the string parameter and call directly the TextBox using its Name, or you choose a DepdendencyProperty bounded to the TextBox's Text property in order to keep in sync with the updates.. overall i suggest you to start using MVVM.